# SSD / HDD choice when write speed is slow - developer workstation and for games

Tags: gaming, hard-disk, ssd

- SanDisk Internal SSD 120GB 2.5-Inch SDSSDA-120G-G25 costs Rs. 3600 (~$53)
- Sandisk SSD 128gb SATA 2.5, Z400s costs Rs. 3800 (~$56)
- SanDisk 128GB SDSSDP-128G-G25 cost Rs. 3900 (~$58)
- Samsung 850 EVO 120GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-75E120B/AM) - Costs Rs. 4800 (~$71)

As of now I have a old 500GB seagate HDD.

The new games are pretty big and system is taking a lot of time to load them (also going for a nwe graphic card since my 4670 got fried few days back).

My doubt in judging them is samsung is costly and has 520mbps write speed, and others have around 180mbps odd.

Some SSDs are slower than HDD when writting small files -do any of the above fall under such categories?

If I have to go with one of them - which is worthy?  I will not upgrade my pc for another 4 -5 years (atleast not my HDD) -I have plenty of room in my external HDD so place is of no issue - Just 128GB is sufficient.

Please advice - SSD (flash and DRAM terms are confusing

My mother board is old and will not change it yet since it is working great.
MB model Asus MT7019015303817.

Another choice: Transcend Ultra 120GB 2.5-inch Solid State Drive with DRAM
64 MB onboard cache/RAID support
Read Speed: Up to 230 Mbps and write speed: Up to 180Mbps
MTBF 1.5 million hours
Costs Rs. 5000 (~$74)

My budget is around Rs. 4500 - Rs. 5000 ($67 - $75)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSDs should never be slower than a HDD, especially in small files. The reason is because of how they work. A HDD uses a spinning platter and a read/write head for information access where a SSD uses a controller with flash chips. When reading/writing files, the HDD has to wait for the head to align with the platter before it can be accessed, but a SSD doesn't have to wait.

In my experience I would only recommend a Sandisk SSD for their reliability, and nothing else. Write speeds are usually less important than read speeds, because if you think about it, you are mostly doing reading of files rather than writing of files. The Samsung SSD will provide significant improvement over the Sandisk ones so I would recommend the Samsung one. You can also look into SSDs from other manufacturers that can be cheaper without sacrificing much performance, such as A-Data, Kingston or Crucial.

Comment: Thank you sharing the knowledge.  Anything on Flash vs Dram ssd, are their any good DRAM SSD?

Comment: @surpavan DRAM SSDs use RAM as their storage. RAM is volatile meaning that it loses it's data when power is lost. Flash (NAND) SSDs are non volatile meaning that it keeps it's data even when power is lost. DRAM based SSDs are much faster but loses their data when power is lost and is generally much more expensive, these are often used for caching to improve performance rather than for storage.